$s^2 + 1$ has no prime factors $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$?
$s^2 + 1$ is the squared length of a vector in a square lattice for every integer $s$. The number of integer
solutions in $a, b$ for $a^2 + b^2 = s^2 + 1$ is of course $> 0$, e.g. $a = s, b = 1$ is a solution.
A lemma to Jacobis theorem about the number of solutions of $a^2 + b^2 = n$ with $n \equiv 1 \mod 4$ states,
that in the factorization of $n$ every prime factor with $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ of $n = s^2 + 1$ has to appear with
an even exponent. A search up to $s = 10^6$ shows: no prime factors  $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$.
Is this true for all $s$ and why?

This is not a research-level question, and should have been posted at https://math.stackexchange.com rather than here. Anyway, “$s^2+1$ has no prime factors $p\equiv3\pmod 4$” is the same thing as “$-1$ is not a square modulo $p\equiv3\pmod4$”, which is a much more basic result than Jacobi’s theorem.
